# Ideas : How to access ideas in communities

Tags: force.com

Ideas has been enabled but is not visible to community users,How to Build a new section on the Community for Ideas so that community users can actually access the ideas section.

Comment: Is your user profiles for community members and moderators have access to Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Salesforce documentation on "[Enable Ideas in Your Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_enable_ideas.htm)". Point 9 and 10 are talking about adding ideas to your community.

9 - Enable user profiles for community members and moderators and ensure the profiles can access Ideas.

10 - Add the Ideas tab and the Idea Themes tab to the community by clicking the Plus icon (Plus icon) that appears to the right of your current tabs and clicking Customize My Tabs on the All Tabs page.

Comment: I had done with points too . But still it is not working